# Creating PHP strings using other variables...works manually, can't figure out how automatically

Tags: php, string, variables, mysql

I'm trying to get a variable to be formed automatically using data pulled from a mysql database.  I know the data is being pulled from the database in some form resembling its original form, but that data does not act the same as data that is manually typed and assigned to a string.

For example, if a cell in a mysql table says...

```
I said "goodbye" before I left.
She also said "goodbye."
```

...and I manually copy/paste it and add the necessary escapes...

```
$string1 = 
"
I said \"goodbye\" before I left.
She also said \"goodbye.\"
";
```

...that does not equal...

```
$string1 = $mysqlResultArray['specificCellWithQuoteShownAbove']
```

Interestingly, if I echo both versions of $string1 and view the output, they appear to be exactly the same.  But they do not function the same when put through various functions I've created.  The functions only work if I do the manual copy/paste method--which is not what I want, obviously.

I'm not sure if it has to do with the line breaks or the escapes--or some combination of the two.  But while both strings are superficially the same, they are apparently functionally different and I don't know why.

So how can I create $string1 without manually copy/pasting the contents from the mysql entry and instead querying for the data and assigning it to $string1 in such a way that it's exactly functionally equivalent as the manual copy/pasted string?

Comment: The syntax in your question is funny. You have one too many double quotes in the second code block. The third code block is also an assignment, not a comparison. I'm pretty sure this was done more cautiously in your code, but you can never be too sure.

Comment: Steven, the double quote was a typo here, not in my code though.  Fixed above :)  And the assignment is meant to be such; the point I was trying to make is that if $string1 is typed out manually, it runs through my function properly.  But if I assign the array element to $string1 (and said element is exactly the same), the function does not run properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your strings aren't the same. You think they are, but they aren't.  The following is a quick and dirty program that will run through two strings and compare them character by character, highlighting any differences.  Add this code to your project, and replace `$first_string` and `$second_string` with the two strings you think are the same, but aren't.

```
function output_chrs($i,$chr_1, $chr_2)
{
    echo $i . '.' . $chr_1, '|', $chr_2;
    if($chr_1 === $chr_2)
    {
        echo "\n";
    }
    else
    {
        echo " <---- difference detected\n";
    }
    return; 
}

function chr_by_chr($string_1, $string_2, $output_method)
{
    if(strlen($string_2) < strlen($string_1))
    {
        $string_2 = str_pad($string_2, strlen($string_1), ' ');
    }
    for($i=0;$i<strlen($string_1);$i++)
    {
        call_user_func($output_method, $i, $string_1[$i], $string_2[$i]);
    }

    if(strlen($string_2) > strlen($string_1))
    {
        for($i=$i;$i<strlen($string_2);$i++)
        {
            call_user_func($output_method, $i, $string_1[$i], $string_2[$i]);
        }
    }
    return;
}

$first_string  =  'foobazbar';
$second_string =  'fora';
$output_method = 'output_chrs';

ob_start();
$results = chr_by_chr($first_string,$second_string,$output_method); 
echo "\n";
$results = chr_by_chr($first_string,$second_string,'output_ords');  

$results = ob_get_clean();
if(isset($argv))
{
    echo $results;
}
else
{
    echo nl2br($results);
}
```

This code will run from the command line or a browser.  As written above, it outputs

```
0.f|f
1.o|o
2.o|r <---- difference detected
3.b|a <---- difference detected
4.a|  <---- difference detected
5.z|  <---- difference detected
6.b|  <---- difference detected
7.a|  <---- difference detected
8.r|  <---- difference detected

0.102|102
1.111|111
2.111|114 <---- difference detected
3.98|97 <---- difference detected
4.97|32 <---- difference detected
5.122|32 <---- difference detected
6.98|32 <---- difference detected
7.97|32 <---- difference detected
8.114|32 <---- difference detected
```

Comment: Alan, 

29.m|m
30. | <---- difference detected
31. |R <---- difference detected
32.R|e <---- difference detected

I'm not sure what difference it detects on line 29, but I can tell you that character 29 is the end of a line.  So I'm not sure what to make of the line break at 30.

Comment: Carriage returns are the difference.  One has them, the other doesn't.  The one that works doesn't.  Let me fix and try again.

Comment: And that was indeed the problem.  Copy/pasting from a plain text source does not paste carriage feeds, whereas they were being picked up by the mysql_query.  Thus I've removed all ascii #13 from the string before feeding through my function.  Thanks for helping out.

Comment: Just wanted to voice my appreciation for Alan's solution - high level of fishing-teaching here :)

Answer (score 0):

You appear to have line breaks at the beginning and end of `$string1`. Change that section to the following:

```
$string1 = "I said \"goodbye\" before I left.
She also said \"goodbye.\"";
```

And you should be cool.

Also, try the following:

```
var_dump($string1);
```

That, unlike `echo` or `print`, will include the string delimiter, so you can more easily see differences between strings.

Comment: I did try that.  Does not make a difference for what I'm working on unfortunately.  But I suspect the line breaks (the way line breaks are stored in a string, maybe?) have something to do with it since the data I'm manipulating has many line breaks.  But beginning and end breaks do not seem to make a difference.

Comment: Did not try var_dump yet.  Let me try now.

Comment: Also, a decent sanity check before going even deeper would be to poll `strlen($str)` of both strings. If they're different, then you're actually dealing with different strings, and a simple manual check via `$str[$i]` will get to the problem character in no time (probably might just come down to a CR issue or something). If they're the same, you're probably dealing with some sort of an encoding mess or something, and we can dig deeper.

Comment: Actually when I do the var_dump, it shows the number of characters at the beginning of the dump.  And there is definitely a difference in the numbers.  I'm scanning through now to figure out where that might be since the two look virtually the same.  Although I'm noticing some spacing and line-breaking differences...I'll report back shortly...

Comment: OK even after ensuring the auto-generated variables and the manual ones are exactly the same, the problem persists.  Only the manually created one works.  I'm totally stumped.

Comment: If `strlen` is the same, that means you're not dealing with some "simple" leading or trailing space or Windows CRLF issue. At this point, I would recommend using `ord` and `array_map` to split the strings into each character and get the ASCII value of each. Then go through it manually. If even that doesn't work, that means you have some wild MySQL encoding issues. Report back, and we can work through those.

Comment: Steven, the mysql result has carriage returns and the manually created string does not.  Let me fix this difference and see what happens.  I'll report back soon...

Comment: SUCCESS! My 6th sense told me it was something about those line breaks...and it was.  The function I send the data through only takes new lines into account (ascii #10), not carriage feeds (ascii #13).  I can either remove the carriage feeds or modify the function--I'd prefer to remove the carriage feeds since the code naturally does not have them if you copy/paste them manually.  Thanks for your help, Steven!

Comment: FYI, your IDE or text editor probably has an option to display non-text characters like \r\n\t. <pedantic> This is why it's generally painful to mix up data and source code. Although it's difficult to avoid in some cases (e.g., if you're hardcoding a parser for some reason), the headaches when you start doing anything complicated like multiline string comparisons or non-ASCII characters or the text encoding mess are just not worth it. </pedantic>

Answer (score 0):

Should work, cannot diagnose the problem from way over here anyways try to using [strcmp](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcmp.php)
and try using `strstr(mystr, strmysql)` to find out what part of string is matching, this will help you troubleshoot the problem

Comment: Problem was the carriage feeds.  That was the difference.  Removed carriage feeds--problem fixed.  Thanks.